# Custom front matter var doesn't work anymore on Jekyll

Tags: variables, jekyll, liquid, var, yaml-front-matter

I have a problem with custom front matter vars that were working fine until now.

I have this in my page :

```
---
has-cart: true;
---
```

and this in an included snippet :
`{% if page.has-cart == true %}lorem ispum{% endif %}`

And it doesn't work anymore. Any idea why ? Thanks

Comment: What is your Jekyll version? Where do you use that code? What have you changed recently?

Comment: Thanks for your intent to help and sorry, it was just a typo :/

Answer (score 0):

Basic typo problem. Yaml front matter doesn't uses `;` as terminator. Correct declaration :

```
---
has-cart: true
---
```